# Electron-builder relative file paths

Tags: javascript, python, electron, electron-builder, python-venv

I'm coding my first app using ElectronJs as a GUI for an older project written in python. When i run my Electron app from the cmd i can successfully activate a python venv using the provided script, run the code written in python and deactivate the venv once the script has exported is results as a file in the out/ folder. All of these actions are handled using the
`child_process.spawn()`
method and launching a powershell instance with my command as parameter (I don't know if there is a bettere way but this works for me!).

When i try to package a portable executable of my Electron app with electron-builder i know that my python manager script written in js runs but my python code doesn't seem to run and i think that somehow my relative paths no longer work.

I use the following path for my python script:

```
const pythonScriptPath = path.join(__dirname, '../python/main.py');
```

Project structure:

```
root:
 + // other files 
 + src:
    |
    + js: //folder with all my js files
    |
    + html: // folder for html
    + css:  // fodlder for css
    |
    + py: // all my python stuff in here
       + venv: // folder for my python env
       + // all my python scripts
```

I need a way to correctly locate my files so my application can run correctly when exported to a portable executable

### Edit

I could use pyInstaller to convert my python code to an executable so i don't really have to deal with all the venv stuff but i don't think this will make my life any easier since i'm not able to execute files (or programs with file paths as argument)

Comment: It's not necessarily related to relative paths. Do you build an ASAR archive when packaging for distribution? If so, try setting `"asar": false` in the Electron Builder configuration. See [Electron's documentation about ASAR caveats](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/asar-archives#limitations-of-the-node-api), too.

Answer (score 0):

this is not about paths being relative, but about how the asar archives work. `child_process.spawn()` simply calls system APIs, and your system doesn't have a way to execute the files from inside your `app.asar`. python doesn't know how to execute code from there either.

a few solutions to put them outside the asar:

1. `extraResources`

put this in your electron-builder config (assuming json):

```json
"extraResources": ["src/py"],
```

do not pack it another time in `files`, there's no reason to. this way, your `src/py` is copied into `resources/src/py` in your electron-builder build.

you can also put it in a different directory, like this:

```json
"extraResources": [{
  "from": "src/py",
  "to": "py"
}],
```

2. `extraFiles`

this works the same as `extraResources`, with the difference that it's put next to the electron binary instead of `resources` subdirectory.

3. `asarUnpack`

you can pack your python code as usual into the asar, as specified in `files`, and use `asarUnpack` to also put an unpacked copy in `resources/app.asar.unpacked`, like this:

```json
"asarUnpack": ["src/py"]
```

I don't recommend this way, because this way your app includes 2 copies of the python code: one is inside the asar (unused by anything), and the other is in `app.asar.unpacked`

Comment: I tried multiple times to use the solution you suggested but it doesn't seem to be working at all :/